# How to find and repair the leak in the framing of a vinyl sliding window?

Tags: windows, leak, siding, vinyl

The panel siding and exterior trim around this window was replaced and painted this Spring. But now seeing major warping and soft wood, inside the red box in photo. Unsure if this is DIY and how to approach. All the exterior seams seem to be sealed, so maybe water is coming in the frame at the sill then filtering down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you hired a contractor to do this work, get with them to fix it. It should still be under warranty. Otherwise, you'll need to start disassembling the trim and siding and investigate for leaking. You can't spend a lot of time theorizing because there's a fair amount of damage/rot based on your statement and you need to correct this fast or more serious problems can arise. Check inside the window frame to make sure there are no cracks exposed especially in the corners.